# How to convert CRC 16 from hexidecimal serie in Python

Tags: python, hex, crc16

I have a serie of hexidecimal bytes:

```
0x81 0x12 0xC0 0x00 0x01 0x05
```

I need to calculate the CRC 16 of this. [An online calcultor gives](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html) me:

```
0x81 0x53 //correct
```

I use the crcmod python module as follows:

```
crc16 = crcmod.predefined.mkCrcFun('crc-16')

print crc16('123456789') # works well

print hex(crc16('\x81\x12\xC0\x00\x01\x05')) #EDIT : works aswell!
```

How can i represent this hexidecimal serie as an ascii string (which the function requieres )

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `'\x81\x12\xC0\x00\x01\x05'`

Comment: @jorrebor, yes, I did so, but what I get is `0x815B`... meanwhile I am using `81 12 C0 00 01 05`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can freely edit your stuff, [Marcus is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12911089/296974), otherwise (e.g. if you have your bytes already somewhere in your program), do

```
values = [0x81, 0x12, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05]
string = "".join(chr(i) for i in values)
print crc16(string)
```